# Share button like the one in photos

Tags: objective-c

I need to create a share screen like the one in the native photos app of IOS, to share some text via several apps to my contacts.

Is there any way to do so ?

I've searched for it a lot and found nothing..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is `UIActivityViewController`.

From the documentation:

> The UIActivityViewController class is a standard view controller that you can use to offer various services from your application. The system provides several standard services, such as copying items to the pasteboard, posting content to social media sites, sending items via email or SMS, and more. Apps can also define custom services.

You can find more information [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/).